# Solve a definite integral with a gaussian integrand.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How do I solve the following integration: 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\:\left(\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}-b^{2}}}\right)^{c}\frac{(x_{0}-x)\, e^{-\alpha\,(x_{0}-x)^{2}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}-b^{2}}}$$
Here, $\alpha,\, b>0$

Comment: and what is $c$?

Comment: $c$ is a real number.

Comment: Use the substitution $x=b\cosh\theta$ and study Bessel functions.

Comment: Also notice that the integrand function is not well defined for $x\in(0,b)$.